# Style a link to be a circle with an arrow inside

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a link centered in a div.

The link should be a circle and have an arrow pointing up.

Basically I need a "go up in page" link ...

I have the following:

```
<div>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

And I have the following CSS:

```
a {
  background: #4679BD;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;          
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Do I need an image to have the arrow. Any other option?

When I insert a letter inside the A tag the letter gets outside of the circle.

Finally, can this be made to be responsive?

Comment: you can use icon fonts for better solution. eg: http://icomoon.io/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get rid of the wrapping div (and the prefixed `border-radius` too), and use [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) instead with an arrow character in the `content` CSS property.

### Result

[image: A magnificent arrow] or  using `\25b2` (and 50px font-size):[image: A much more magnificent arrow]

### HTML

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

### CSS

```
a {
    background: #4679BD;
    text-decoration:none; /* Remove that ugly underlining */
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
a::after {
    content:"\2191";   /* The code for the arrow : see the reference */
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 60px; /* Adjust for your needs */
    text-align: center;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PyuxX/)

### Bonus

[A list of useful HTML and CSS entities!](http://mcdlr.com/8/)

Responsive? Using sizes relative to the font size (like `em`, `rem`...) instead of px, yes.

Responsive to the screen size itself? No, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks ! This works perfectly for me. I wasted several hours on this until I decided to take your solution.

Comment: Can you please explain how the pseudo element is falling inside the link and not on next line ? I thought that block elements always fall on new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the html up arrow entity `&#x2191;`, and some styling like so:

```
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px; // needs to be same as height
  margin: 100px auto;
}

div a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
```

See [codepen](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/d5ca9d4d285b73be598d712474c5bc84/)

Comment: Applying the radius and other porperties to the div has a problem: when I apply and hover to the anchor to change the color of the circle on mouse hover this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make triangles with css using borders like this, but if you want actual arrows, it would probably be easier to use an image.

Is this what you're looking for?

I moved your css to the div and gave the a this styling:

`a {
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid black;
}`

Then just adjusted the position of the triangle slightly.

http://jsfiddle.net/jHWzZ/1/

EDIT:

you can add hover like so:

`a:hover{
       border-bottom: 25px solid red;

}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#">&rarr;</a>



a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
}

a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
}
```